# ForEach extension method

Tags: c#, linq

I'm a bit confused over a line of code:

```
Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

This line does what it says it does, it prints out each number from 1 to 10 with a line break inbetween each of them, all that with one neat little line of code..

Now I'm only a C# novice at best, but it looks completely foreign to me, how can we call `Console.WriteLine()` without providing it with any arguments? How does it know what it's going to print? From this syntax it's not even clear to me that we're calling on a method (considering the lack of paranthesis around `WriteLine`).

I'm assuming that there's a lot of stuff going on "behind the scenes" here but I'm not very good at reading IL code, from what I've gathered reading the MSIL it seems like `ForEach` calls a generic delegate(`System.Action`) on each element in the collection, I am guessing that it then passes the element as an argument to the `System.Action` delegate but that's only my guess..

Comment: your guess is correct try to dive more in Action and delegate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an implicit conversion from a method group (`Console.WriteLine` in this case) and a compatible delegate type. You code is effectively the same as

```
Action<int> f = Console.WriteLine;
Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToList().ForEach(f);
```

The delegate `f` is compatible with the method [`void Console.WriteLine(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70x4wcx1.aspx)

Comment: I have to admit, that is absolutely mind boggling to me. Where are the conversions being done in your code example?

Comment: @OverlyExcessive - From the method group `Console.WriteLine` to the delegate `Action<int>`.

Comment: But what is happening here? Is it selecting the one overload of the Writeline that takes an int?

Comment: @OverlyExcessive - Yes, `f` will call that overload of `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: @Lee, assisting Overly, the basics is, that ForEach expects a function that returns nothing and takes an int parameter. It expects the int parameter, because it is used on a List of type int. A lambda can be said to be short hand for quickly providing such a function, but ForEach can take any existing function. Console.WriteLine is such a function, and because the ForEach knows it must have a function with an int parameter, it will automatically use the proper overload.

Comment: I think I actually get it now, in a way I already knew that delegates worked this way, but the syntax just threw me off. I have to say, what an absolutely awesome neat little way to print a sequence of successive numbers in just one line of code!

Comment: Yep, Linq and Lamdas rule bigtime :) oh, and sorry Lee, had the names reversed, meant assisting your post and an @ overly, but I guess that was clear already.

Answer (score 2):

```
Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine)
```

is short for

```
Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToList().ForEach(text => Console.WriteLine(text));
```

it is called a MethodGroup

Comment: Right, but I don't understand how that is possible. If it's lambda shouldn't we be forced to use a lambda? Or is it an overloaded method?

Comment: it is expecting a method with a signature of void method that takes one int parameter. You can call Console.WriteLine, or you can put any other method like `DoSmth(int i)`

Comment: it's convention based. since 'text' is the only parameter that goes in and the method has no return value, the lambda can be stripped.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach statement is a generic one, and in your case it is a `ForEach<int>`. It takes one argument of type `Action<int>` and any void method accepting single `int` parameter will work for this purpose. `Console.WriteLine` is one of such methods